# Getting http 403 on uploading images

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, upload, firebase-storage

I keep getting this error:

> POST
> https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/talknote-48adf.appspot.com/o?name=%5Bobject%20Object%5D%2FprofilePicture%2F02.jpg
> 403 ()

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Here is my code:

```
 var uploader = document.getElementById('uploader');
 var fileButton = document.getElementById('fileButton');

 //Listen for file 
 fileButton.addEventListener('change', function(e){

 //Get File
 var file = e.target.files[0];
 // Get current username
 var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

 //Create a Storage Ref
 var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(user + '/profilePicture/' + file.name);

 //Upload file
 var task = storageRef.put(file);     

 //Update Progress Bar 
 task.on('state_changed', 

 function progress(snapshot){
    var percentage = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) *100;
    uploader.value = percentage;

    //if percentage = 100
    //$(".overlay").hide();         
 },

 function error(err){

 },

 function complete(){

 }

   );           
});
```

And here is the firebase rule:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/talknote-48adf.appspot.com/o {
    match /{userId}/profilePicture/{fileName} {
      // Anyone can read
      allow read;
      // Only the user can upload their own profile picture
      // Profile picture must be of content-type "image/*"
      allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId
                   && request.resource.contentType.matches('image/.+');
    }
  }
}
```